# drf-passwordless Override EmailAuthSerializer to add custom fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, overriding, password-less

In `drf-passwordless` (https://github.com/aaronn/django-rest-framework-passwordless), is it possible to override this class to allow adding other custom fields?
e.g. In my case is an administrator who register the user email. I already modified the send_email_with_callback_token function to include the token into a link but I also want to be able to add other custom codes to the link so that the user will be redirected appropriately based on the administrator wishes.

How do I override this class to add some more serialisers fields? Thanks.

```py
class EmailAuthSerializer(AbstractBaseAliasAuthenticationSerializer):
    @property
    def alias_type(self):
        return 'email'

    email = serializers.EmailField()
```